# In Angular, does `name` in `<input [value]="name">` mean string literal or a property?

Tags: angular5

In the following code

```
<input [value]="name">
```

Is name a string literal or a property? I understand the code inside the double quotes is an expression. So I suppose `name` should be a property defined in my component class. If that is the case, is is possible to assign a string literal to `value` i.e. `[value]="name"` where `name` is not a property of an object but a literal? Would I have to remove the `[]` so that `name` gets assigned to the `value` attribute of `input` and not `value` property?

Comment: When you use the `[...]` type of syntax on the inputs for a component/directive, whatever in the `"..."` is considered code. So, in your case it would be setting the `value` property to the value of the `name` variable in your component. Angular does a great job discussing this in their documentation for template syntax https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax

Comment: Thanks. So if I want to make `"..."` a string, I should not use the square brackets?

Comment: Yeah. `<input value="name">` or `<input [value]="'name'">` (notice the single quotes that make `name` a string)

Comment: thanks. Happy to accept your answer if you could change your comment to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of the square brackets is called a binding, so taking the two examples from the comments:

```
<input [value]="name">
```

This would bind the variable `name` to the value of the input element. If you update the `name` variable in your code the input value shown will change. Note this is one-way binding, meaning that if you change the input text, your name variable will not update with the new value. For that use case you'd use `[(value)]="name"`

```
<input [value]="'name'">
```

This would bind the string literal 'name' to the value of the input element, so the input would should the literal text `name`